How to access the global instance manager on Laravel Blade
How do I access the global instance manager for  Flowbite.  I followed this guide but the instructions are not very clear.
I am trying to access it on my Laravel blade.
It says you can access the global instance manager like this:
let modal;

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    modal = FlowbiteInstances.getInstance('Modal', 'modal-id');
})

modal.show();

however, I keep getting the message:
688 Uncaught ReferenceError: modal is not defined 

This is the Modal:
 <div
    id="modal-id"
    tabindex="-1"
    aria-hidden="true"
    class="fixed left-0 right-0 top-0 z-50 hidden h-[calc(100%-1rem)] max-h-full w-full overflow-y-auto overflow-x-hidden p-4 md:inset-0"
>
    
</div>

Edit:
Declaring Flowbite at  /resources/js/app.js:
import 'flowbite';

UPDATE -
this worked thanks to silver. I had to add a setTimer method.
<script type="application/javascript">

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {


        setTimeout(function () {
            FlowbiteInstances.getInstance("Modal", "login-modal").show();
            // or replace this with the button click
        }, 1000);

    
</script>


Can you please edit your question and share the modal part of the blade template that you want to show? The error clearly says that you need to pass the actual target ID or parent ID of the main element instead of modal-id.Share your blade template.

hi @Subha- thank you for replying. I have edited my question to add part of the modal

Your code seems to be correct to me .But modal is not defined means that flowbite JavaScript package is not properly loaded.Have you imported this js package either into /resources/js/app.js or using external library?

you are declaring a variable inside a block then tries to access it outside, that wont work

@PaulKendal above comment by "silver" is another potential point that I missed. Also check it.

@Subha  - i have edited my answer and added the variable outside the block.  i think Subha is correct the issue is that flowbite is not properly loaded.  I did however try to import flowbite into my app.js.  Subha,  please what is the proper way to import the flowbite  in Laravel

you cant access "modal" object because you declare "modal" in another scope
    let modal;

    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        modal = FlowbiteInstances.getInstance('Modal', 'modal-id');
    })
    
    modal.show();


take a look at
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#block_scoping

thank you, I made the change but still got this error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'show')
